# How to create css3 background versions for different browsers?

Tags: css, background, gradient, linear-gradients

I am new to CSS and not sure how to create different version of the css snippet below for all browsers:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #66BAC0;
```

I got it from somewhere on the web but it doesn't have other vendor prefixes or browser types.  How can I do this using an online tool or by doing it manually?

Comment: there are tons of resources for this on the web. Heck, there are tons of resources for this just here on SO. Did you really not find them when you searched??

Comment: I can't find one that will generate a similar code to the one above.

Comment: pretty much any of the questions linked to the right in the "Related" column will have relevant code for you.

Comment: I have a hard time believing searching for *css gradient* comes up with something other than http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ as the #1 result.  95% of all prefixed properties can be copy/pasted with just a modification to the prefix portion (eg. `-moz-linear-gradient` becomes `-webkit-linear-gradient`).

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0px,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1affffff', endColorstr='#1a000000',GradientType=0 );
```

I really recommend this site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - it allows you to easily create cross browser CSS gradients.

Comment: I tried it but I don't get the same color.  It seems to turn to gray.

Comment: Here's link to it on the colorzilla site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,000000+100&0.1+0,0.1+100;Custom - what browser are you using?

Comment: I am testing on firefox, chrome, safari.  The code i posted in my question works on firefox but not on chrome and safari.

Comment: The reason your code isn't working properly is because you're using the vendor prefix `-moz` which non-Firefox browsers don't recognise. Just copy all my code in place of your line and it will work everywhere.

Comment: it doesn't work.  i tried it many times.

Comment: Here's a demo showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/7eLmN/ - I've just tested it in Safari, Chrome and Firefox,